# How to connect two x16 nor flash to nor flash controller?

Tags: flash, bus

There is a nor flash controller with 32bit data bus and 26 address PINs, which mean it can access 64MB space. Now we connect two 32M byte x16 nor flash to the nor flash controller, D[0~15] connect to nor flash 0 and D[16~31] connect to nor flash 1. Both nor flash share the same chip select and misc PINs. I want to know how the Address lines should be connected? Shall we connect nor flash controller's A0-A23 to both nor flash's A0~A23, or shall we connect nor flash controller's A2~A25 to both nor flash's A0~A23? Or, both are wrong, and what's the right way?

Btw: both nor flash has 24 address PINs and the address is not byte address but word address.